# Is it moral or immoral for Satan to punish souls for immoral acts?

Tags: satan

Satan, to my understanding, punishes souls in hell as a result of their immoral acts on earth.  It also is my understanding that the concept of Satan represents pure immorality (evil).

Does that mean it is *immoral* to punish souls in hell or is it actually *moral*?

Comment: You may enjoy reading [this](http://www.orthodoxpress.org/parish/river_of_fire.htm) for an alternate (Eastern Orthodox) perspective, which differs radically from Western Christianity on this issue.

Comment: I have some confusion. Which actions are you referring to as moral/immoral? Do you mean God's action of throwing people to Hell or Satan's action of punishing people in Hell?

Comment: Can you back up your question with scripture?  Anyway, the devil comes to steal, kill and destroy. So needless to say, it'd be hell down there.

Comment: You are confusing Christianity with Greek mythology.

Comment: Hi rpeg, as Dan mentioned there are various views regarding hell, this article presents one perspective that may be helpful - http://willfults.com/hell-burn-eternity/

Comment: The majority of religion is "opinion-based".

Answer (score 11):

In Dante's Inferno, that may have been the case, however, in the Bible, that is absolutely not the case.  Satan was never given dominion over hell.  In fact, Revelation 19 and 20 tells us Satan will be bound and thrown into the Abyss for 1000 years.  After his release, he will be cast into the Lake of Fire with Death, the Grave, the Beast and the False Prophet to burn forever.  Satan receives eternal punishment for his actions according to the Bible.  Aside from 14th Century literature, he never gets to take his revenge out on anyone.  In other words, Satan does not ever punish any souls for immoral acts according to the Bible.

As for the morality of "punishing" someone in Hell, I would contest that as well.  I would say a person who rejects God has chosen Hell over Heaven and God forcing a person who wanted nothing to do with Him in life to spend eternity with Him in a relationship they didn't want is tantamount to kidnapping.  Think Jayce Dugard.  *That* would be the truly immoral thing to do.

Comment: Okay. Thanks.  Are there some Christian sects that believe Satan has dominion over hell?

Comment: Unfortunately, thanks to Dante, Bugs Bunny, TV commercials, biker t-shirts and other media and memorabilia, combined with a general illiteracy of the Bible among Christians, I would have to say there are many Christians who believe eternal punishment is meted out by Satan.

Comment: Also, as an example, are you saying that someone born into the tradition of Vodou, who never learns of Christianity, has "chosen" hell?

Comment: If we are to understand Romans 1 as saying God reveals Himself to every person on the planet throughout history by means of natural revelation, visions, etc., and they follow something else instead, then yes, they have rejected Him.  There is also a theory that has been making the rounds lately that perhaps God, in His Sovereignty, knew ahead of time which people would never accept the gospel no matter how many times they heard it and had them be born someplace they never are exposed to it.  I'm not sure I'm ready to sign off on that one.

Comment: Let me see if I understand this Mark Anthony Songer.  You're saying that someone who might claim they've never heard of Christianity _secretly_ has heard of it and because of this, they are choosing hell?  You're argument feels extremely untenable.

Comment: Well, I didn't say "secretly".  And the question of "what happens to those people who never hear the gospel" has been wrestled with for 1900+ years without a solution.  I gave the two most popular current theories. What I did say, the one I would choose if I had to, is that the Bible says everyone gets a chance one way or another.  That argument is based on what Paul writes in Romans 1:18-23.  I wish I could post the whole passage here but it is too long.  Read it and that will give us a common ground for this discussion.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10449/discussion-between-mark-anthony-songer-and-rpeg)

Comment: @rpeg- it is likely contrary to what many feel, but what is clear is that God reveals himself to all through his creation.  It may also be possible that those who do not know the name of Christ will be given the name prior to judgement.  Ie, someone could believe without knowing the name such that they would know the name when they heard it and call upon it.  Basically, if someone is presented with Vodoo, realizes something else is truth but isn't sure what, they would call upon it as soon as it was revealed to them.  There are actually reported cases of things like this happening.

Comment: Something is unclear in your answer. If you mean to say that eternal punishment is not meted out by Satan, please mention it clearly in your answer.

Answer (score 5):

Satan does not punish anyone for sin.  Punishment for sin is solely and exclusively claimed as a right by God.  Romans 12:19 makes this abundantly clear when it says

```
19 Do not take revenge, my dear friends, but leave room for God’s wrath, 
for it is written: “It is mine to avenge; I will repay,”[a] says the Lord.
```

Answer (score 2):

In Matthew 25:31-46, Jesus gives us a picture of the Judgement. Notice that there are ONLY 2 groups. The ones on the right, His sheep, those that followed Him, will

> inherit the kingdom **prepared for you** from the foundation of the
>   world (v. 34)

; and the ones on His left, the goats, who chose not to follow in His footsteps, will go

> into everlasting fire, prepared **for the devil and his angels** (v. 41)

Notice that heaven was prepared for us, but the fire was prepared to the devil and his angels. Revelation 20 also gives us a closer look into Judgement.

It is the same, the people who have received the seal of God, whose names were written in the Book of Life, they will sit on thrones; while the devil, his angels, and those who were not found written in the Book of Life are cast into the lake of fire. If we follow the succession of Revelation 20, the devil and his angels are tossed in the lake of fire first and then the ones not found in the Book of Life. Then it says,

> And death and hell were cast into the lake of fire. This is the second
>   **death**. And whosoever was not found written in the book of life was
>   cast into the lake of fire. (Rev. 20:14, 15)

Satan is cast into the lake of fire, the second death, eternal death and separation from God, because they did not wish to follow the Truth that was revealed to them.

There are many schools of thought on the matter. Based on the parables of Jesus **it seems to me** that the punishment, hell, will come AFTER the Judgement. I think this is only fair because it would be unfair to condemn someone to 10 years of prison without a fair trial and judgement. In the same way it would not be fair to send people to burn in hell and then be judged. This is a VAST subject and cannot be comprehensively discussed in detail in a single post.

In short, Satan does not punish anyone in hell, because no one has been judged and condemned.